# How do I enable WebBrowser in an application used for 3D Animation in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, webbrowser-control

I was trying to do flipping affect on the UIElements(Image/Page) Horizontally by keeping the UIElements at the fixed Place(I mean by staying at origin(0,0,0) position ).I did it in 3D animation, now while I am going to flip it by using Web browser in place of these UIElements this is not showing the content of the web Browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to apply 3D effects on WPF's built-in WebBrowser, because it is just a thin wrapper around the native ActiveX-Webbrowser, which isn't based on WPF. There is a basic browser that works with such effects, don't know if it fits your needs, but you can have a look:
[WPF WebBrowser (Chris Cavanagh's blog)](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/a-real-wpf-webbrowser/)